# How do I get the last <li> item in a unordered list & place it at the top of the list, using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I was wondering is there any way to get the last item in a unordered `<ul>` list and place it at the top of the list...kind of like a continuous loop?

Sorry I'm a novice at JQuery

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) or [`.prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/), like this:

```
$("#myUL li:last").prependTo("#myUL")
```

This uses [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) to get the last one them prepends it to the same list, inserting it at the beginning.

Comment: @Nick - Thanks for you help...I'm trying to re-create the Top Tweets  widget on the Twitter ( http://twitter.com ) homepage. Is there a way of writing a simple version of the widget? I'm also using a static unordered list. Thanks

Comment: @Nasir - For that you could just `overflow: hidden` the container, and when adding the top tweet to this: `$("#myUL li:last").hide().prependTo("#myUL").slideDown()` so it gets that sliding effect when it appears.

Comment: @Nick - OK great...it gets the last item and places it at the top of the list. How do I get this process to keep looping after a short delay?

Comment: @Nasir - just use `setInterval()` to call your function that does that, for example: `function myFunc() { ...do stuff... } setInterval(myFunc, 2000);` for 2 seconds

Comment: @Nick - Thanks a trillion...great stuff :)

Comment: @All - Here's all the code for this SUPER simple list rotator:

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 function tweet(){
  $("#in-auction-cycle-content li:last").hide().prependTo("#in-auction-cycle-content").slideDown();
 };
 setInterval(tweet,2000);

});